# How can I force my textfield to not move the "camera" (focus) while writing

Tags: swift

I want to have to focus of my textfield always at the beginning of the textfield even if the user is writing, I want that the user always see the first word he typed.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of thing I usually use two textfields, the "real one" which is behind the one the user sees and the one the user sees which is in front, has user interaction turned off, and is covered by another view with a tap gesture recognizer (or just a clear button).

When the user taps on the empty view or button, you tell the real textfield to become first responder.  As the user types in the textfield you implement the delegate methods and forward whatever filtered or formatted input you want to the visible textfield in front.